# Working with Laravel and AngularJs

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, laravel

First sorry about my english i will do my best to explain.
I recently started a project what will use heavy javascript, specially lot of ajax calls and ajax manipulations.

For example lke

- facebook style dropdown notification
- lot of different ajax forms
- like button
- follow button
- image manupulations and uploads

I made similar with jQuery back in time and jQuery is the only library i know yet.
But i was eyeing with AngularJs studied a lot about it and i am likeing it.

I was searching for Laravel + AngularJs tutorial but did not find any useful information for my answer.

So when i use jQuery for example, and i would like to retrive data from an attribute, or sending a form, i have to give it a `class` or `id`, but angular uses controllers.

So my question is it okay to mix the controllers with the view?

Example

```
<?php echo  Form::open() ?>

    <?php echo  Form::label('password', 'Password') ?>
    <?php echo  Form::password('password', array('class' => 'span4')) ?>
    <span class="help-block">5-12 characters.</span>
    <?php echo  $errors->has('password') ? $errors->first('password', '<p class="validation-error">:message</p>') : ''?>

    <?php echo  Form::label('confirm_password', 'Confirm password') ?>
    <?php echo  Form::password('confirm_password', array('class' => 'span4')) ?>
    <?php echo  $errors->has('confirm_password') ? $errors->first('confirm_password', '<p class="validation-error">:message</p>') : ''?>

    <div ng-controller="PhotoCtrl">
        //on image change preform auto upload
    </div>

    <?php echo  Form::button('Sign up', array('class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success')) ?>

<?php echo  Form::close() ?>
```

So in the above code what i posted, you see the ng-controller, mixing the 2 this way is good or bad?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and yes it's fine to use those together, but sometimes you might want to consider writing a directive instead of a full controller.

Directives can be written to handle small bits of functionality, where controllers group a bunch of actions together.

Comment: thanks, yes i was thinking about that, i just wanted to be usre with the controller part, and thanks